# How to get attribute from selected option of select in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, html-select

I have the next **selectbox** in HTML:

```
<select id="listbox-taskStatus" class="selectpicker">
    <option status="0">In progress</option>
    <option status="1">Not started</option>
    <option status="2">Done</option>
    <option status="3">Failed</option>
</select>
```

I want to read the attribute value from selected option.

If just to take the value, it's simple:

```
var value = $('#listbox-taskStatus').val();
```

But what should I do, if I want to get the attribute value from selected option?
I know, that **.attr()** must help, but when I tried to use it I've got the incorrect result.

I've tried the next:

```
var status = $('#listbox-taskStatus option').attr('status');
```

But the returned value is always `0` despite on fact I was selecting different option.

What's wrong, how to solve my problem?

Comment: `$('#listbox-taskStatus option')` gets all of the `option` elements. You just want the selected one.

Comment: @undefined , because it's not value. Even jQuery have made special function `.val()` fro getting values from DOM elements, and the value of <option> is inside its tag. So as for me I can't name the attribute as `value`, but it's my own opinion. Of course it's a vexed question, but I think it's some freedom for naming the attributes.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) Selector

```
var status = $('#listbox-taskStatus option:selected').attr('status');
```

However, I would recommend you to use `data-` prefixed attribute. Then you can use `.data()`

```
var status = $('#listbox-taskStatus option:selected').data('status');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/2huvy0db/)

Answer (score -1):

```
var optionAttr1 = $('#listbox-taskStatus').find('option:selected').attr("status");
var optionAttr = $('#listbox-taskStatus option:selected').attr("status");
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.